# How to keep Java Swing action handler in one place?

Tags: java, swing, listener

I am writing a swing interface with multiple panels which are distributed in multiple classes. I now want to implement mouse and Key listener for multiple of these panels.
I wander if there is a good way to keep all the user interaction in one place (possibly a listener class).

My current code would look similar to this:

```
class Panel1 extends JPanel{
    public Panel1() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                do_something();
            }
        });
    }
    void do_something(){
        ...
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel{
    public Panel2() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                do something different
            }
        });
    }
}

class Panel3 ...
```

Comment: My opinion : Create MouseAdapter or KeyListener class and invoke it in all classes like a method.   ' 
class GuiControl {
   public void startButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      System.out.println("start button pushed");
   }

   public void endButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      System.out.println("end button pushed");
   }
}'

Comment: you mean only mouse actions?